# Last Month Data Formula

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a custom table that has the below information in MS SQL 2014.  I am trying to come up with a way to calculate the following formula.

> ABS(LastMonthTotal + LastMonthNew – ThisMonthTotal) = Decoms

i.e. ABS(AugustTotal + AugustNew – SeptemberTotal).  This should yield 557.

I was thinking of using case statements inside of the ABS, but can't get it to work properly.

```
  creationmonth MonthCreated    TotalCount  NewCount    RetreivedON

  8             August          11238       1629        8/1/2016 0:00

  9             September       12310       721         9/1/2016 0:00
```

This is what I came up with so far, but it doesn't work.  I was hoping after I got this part working, I could get the dynamic part working to look for this month and last month.

abs((case when CreationMonth = '8' then totalcount end) + (case when CreationMonth = '8' then newcount end) - (case when creationmonth = '9' then totalcount end))

Comment: Could you post your current attempt at it involving the case statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perfect opportunity to use a window function:

```
SELECT 
 LAG(TotalCount) OVER (ORDER BY CreationMonth) AS LastMonthTotal 
,LAG(NewCount) OVER (ORDER BY CreationMonth) AS LastMonthNew 
,TotalCount AS ThisMonthTotal
,ABS(LAG(TotalCount) OVER (ORDER BY CreationMonth) 
   + LAG (NewCount) OVER (ORDER BY CreationMonth) 
   - TotalCount) AS Decoms
from TableX;
```

The LAG function will give you the value form the previous row. 'Previous row' is defined by the order in the `OVER` clause. In this case you just order by the creationmonth.

Comment: I can't upvote this because I'm new to the site, but it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

something like

```
ABS(LastMonthTotal + LastMonthNew – LEAD(ThisMonthTotal, 1,0)OVER (ORDER BY  RetreivedON asc)  )
```